# SAS - Passing date from one file to another program variable

Tags: date, sas

I am looking for the correct way to pass a date in Date9. format from one source file (could be a text file) to another sas program file.

In my SAS program I have the following:

```
%MACRO Getdate;
DATA getDate;
infile 'h:\dates.txt';
input @1 date9.;
run;
%MEND Getdate;
```

The conent of the file dates.txt is something like this:
28JAN2014

I am not sure how to get this date out into a variable so that i can use it in another macro To set the start date and end date for a certain query.

Sorry I am new to SAS and am trying to learn it as quickly as possible just wanted to know how i might go around solving this problem.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. Check doco for the `symput` function inside of your data step. You probably don't need a named dataset, you could just use `data _null_`.

Comment: Thanks sasfrog, i did look these up and Reese's logic below helped me solve the problem. Definitely appreciate your input nonetheless :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the call symputX, with the Global option to make sure the macro variable is available outside the macro.  I'd wonder why you'd need a macro for this at all though :).
You may also want to read up on how SAS stores dates, as they're numbers with formats applied.

```
%MACRO Getdate;
DATA _null_;
infile 'h:\dates.txt';
input @1 date date9.;
call symputx('date_stored', put(date, date9.), G);
run;
%MEND Getdate;

%getdate;

%put &date_stored.;
```

EDIT: Based on your answer/comments below:

```
%MACRO Getdate;
%let date_stored=0;
DATA _null_;
infile 'h:\dates.txt';
input @1 date date9.;
call symputx('date_stored', put(date, date9.), G);
call symputx('start_date', put(date-45, date9.), G);
call symputx('end_date', put(date-14, date9.), G);
run;


%MEND Getdate;

*CHECK if they exist after macro is run;
%put &date_stored;
%put &start_date;
%put &end_date;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Reese :))), this absolutely worked for me. I was able to get the date and do my own manipulations with it. I gave your answer the green check, since I still don't have the rep points to give you a +1

Answer (score 0):

So using Reese's logic, I formulated my answer as follows:

```
%MACRO Getdate;
%let date_stored=0;
DATA _null_;
infile 'h:\dates.txt';
input @1 date date9.;
call symputx('date_stored', put(date, date9.), G);
run;

%put &date_stored;

%let start_date=%SYSFUNC(INTNX(day,"&date_stored"d,-45),date9.);
%let end_date=%SYSFUNC(INTNX(day,"&date_stored"d,-14),date9.);
%put &start_date;
%put &end_date;

%MEND Getdate;
%getdate;
```

Comment: Check your variable scopes. Does &start_date and &end_date exist once your %getdate macro has run? I wouldn't expect it to...

Comment: You could also move your start/end date calculation right into your data _null_ step to avoid the macro calculations.

Comment: Thanks Resse for the tip, I will keep this mind. And now that I have enough rep points I am going to +1 your answer :) Thanks for your time and help, deeply appreciated